# Manual for CLISP

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, manpage

I want to read help for clisp function from REPL or just from shell. 
I found (symbol-plist) function for this which give this:

```
(symbol-plist 'bit)
(SYSTEM::TYPE-SYMBOL #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::TYPE-SYMBOL-BIT>
 SYSTEM::SETF-EXPANDER SYSTEM::STORE SYSTEM::DOC
 (CLHS "Body/any_bit.html" SYSTEM::FILE
  ((DEFSETF #P"/build/buildd/clisp-2.49/debian/build/places.fas" 941 941))))
```

but it's not so useful info in order to understand how does (bit) works?

So are there any manuals and documentation for clisp function something like man in shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[7]> (describe 'bit)

BIT is the symbol BIT, lies in #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP>, is accessible in 9 packages CLOS, COMMON-LISP, COMMON-LISP-USER, EXPORTING, EXT,
POSIX, REGEXP, SCREEN, SYSTEM, names a function, names a type, has 3 properties SYSTEM::TYPE-SYMBOL, SYSTEM::SETF-EXPANDER, SYSTEM::DOC.
ANSI-CL Documentation is at
"http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/any_bit.html"
For more information, evaluate (SYMBOL-PLIST 'BIT).

 #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is the package named COMMON-LISP. It has 2 nicknames LISP, CL.
 It imports the external symbols of 1 package CLOS and exports 978 symbols to 8 packages REGEXP, POSIX, EXPORTING, SCREEN, CLOS,
 COMMON-LISP-USER, EXT, SYSTEM.

 #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION BIT> is a built-in system function.
 Argument list: (#:ARG0 &REST SYSTEM::OTHER-ARGS)
 For more information, evaluate (DISASSEMBLE #'BIT).

Documentation:
CLHS:
"Body/any_bit.html"
SYSTEM::FILE:
((DEFSETF #P"/Lisp/clisp/clisp-2.49/src/places.fas" 941 941))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this may be of interest. Below is a short extract:

> [Function] bit bit-array &rest subscripts  sbit simple-bit-array &rest
>   subscripts
>
> bit is exactly like aref but requires an array of bits, that is, one
>   of type (array bit). The result will always be 0 or 1. sbit is like
>   bit but additionally requires that the first argument be a simple
>   array (see section 2.5). Note that bit and sbit, unlike char and
>   schar, allow the first argument to be an array of any rank.

[Bit Function clisp](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node161.html)

Also, [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/) is a huge index of links to appropriate section(s) of the clisp manual.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'd like to run this help from shell if it's possible.

Comment: Common Lisp the Language is superseded by the ANSI Common Lisp standard. Use the Hyperspec or similar.